# How to Delete an item from an array with specific string matching

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to match a specific string (full match not partial match) and then delete that specific item from the array if it matches.

I have some code but it doesn't seem to be deleting the item from the array. I do wish for it to change the original array and not create a new array so I am not using filter.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Current Code:

```js
let recentSearches = [
  { name: "Chicago, IL" },
  { name: "Orlando, FL" },
  { name: "Dallas, TX" }
];

let stringToRemove = "Dallas, TX";

recentSearches.some(recent => {
  if (recent.name === stringToRemove) {
    const index = recentSearches.indexOf(stringToRemove);

    if (index !== -1) { //Never goes into this if
      recentSearches.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(recentSearches);
    }
  }
});

console.log(recentSearches);
```

JS Fiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/e2pt4vm8/)

Comment: It's not an array of strings, it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the output being a different array, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const filteredSearches = recentSearches.filter((recent) => recent.name !== stringToRemove);
```

If you need to modify the array in-place, you should visit the elements in reverse order (in case of multiple matches, which causes indices to shift) like so:

```js
for (let i = recentSearches.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (recentSearches[i].name === stringToRemove) {
    recentSearches.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

The problem with your code is you use `recentSearches.indexOf`, but `recentSearches` isn't an array of strings, so nothing matches.  You could modify your code as follows, but it won't work correctly in case of multiple mathces:

```js
recentSearches.forEach((recent, index) => {
  if (recent.name === stringToRemove) {
    recentSearches.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (as suggested in other comments and answers) as follows:

```js
let index;
while (0 <= (index = recentSearches.findIndex((recent) => recent.name === stringToRemove)) {
  recentSearches.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf()` is for finding exact matches. Since your array contains objects, they'll never be equal to `stringToRemove`.

Use `findIndex()` to get the index of an array element using a function that an compare the `name` property.

There's also no need for using `some()`.

```js
let recentSearches = [{
    name: "Chicago, IL"
  },
  {
    name: "Orlando, FL"
  },
  {
    name: "Dallas, TX"
  }
];

let stringToRemove = "Dallas, TX";

const index = recentSearches.findIndex(({
  name
}) => name == stringToRemove);
if (index !== -1) { //Never goes into this if
  recentSearches.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(recentSearches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON search is done wrongly.

I have added the perfect code to complete your requirement. Find all instances and delete them with a while loop. This will ensure duplicate search terms are also removed if any.

```
let recentSearches = [
    {name: "Chicago, IL"},
    {name: "Orlando, FL"},
    {name: "Dallas, TX"}
];
  
let stringToRemove = "Dallas, TX";

while (recentSearches.findIndex(search => search.name === stringToRemove) > -1) {
    const index = recentSearches.findIndex(search => search.name === stringToRemove);
    recentSearches.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(recentSearches);
```

Comment: @PA-GW ensure to add a while block to make sure the code is corner-case covered.

Comment: Oh sorry, the author corrected it now. Initially, it was like `let stringToRemove = "Dallax, TX";`

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the findIndex, instead of using while, you could use for, a slight advantage here is that the index is then locally scoped inside the the for, were with a while loop you have the extra scope of the index, you could close the the scope of a let by doing `{ let index; while() {..}}` but the for loop avoids that without using `{}`.

```js
let recentSearches = [
    {name: "Chicago, IL"},
    {name: "Orlando, FL"},
    {name: "Dallas, TX"}
];
  
let stringToRemove = "Dallas, TX";

for (let index; index = recentSearches.findIndex(
  search => search.name === stringToRemove), index > -1;) 
    recentSearches.splice(index, 1);

console.log(recentSearches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findindex.
Store it in a variable.
And use splice

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Array.prototype._arraycopy =  function(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length) {
  while ((--length) >= 0) {
    dest[destPos++] = src[srcPos++];
  }
};

Array.prototype._fastRemove = function(es, i) {
  let newSize;
  if ((newSize = this.length - 1) > i) 
    this._arraycopy(es, i + 1, es, i, newSize - i);
  es[this.length = newSize] = null;
  this.length = newSize;
}

Array.prototype.__removeAt = function(index) {
  // Objects.checkIndex(index, size);
    const es = this;

    const oldValue =es[index];
    this._fastRemove(es, index);
    return oldValue;
}

Array.prototype.__removeAtValue = function(o) {
  const es = this;
  const size = this.size;
  let i = 0;
  (function() {
    if (o == null) {
        for (; i < size; i++)
            if (es[i] == null)
                return true;
    } else {
        for (; i < size; i++)
            if (Object.is(o, es[i]))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
  })()
  this._fastRemove(es, i);
  return true;
}

Array.prototype.remove = function(index) {
  return this.__removeAt(index)

}

Array.prototype.removeObj = function(obj) {
  return this.__removeAtValue(obj);
}

const arr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 10];
console.log(arr);
const rem = arr.remove(1)
console.log({ arr, rem });

const objs = [{ id: 1, name: "Hello" }, { id: 2, name: "Arrow" }, { id: 3, name: "Star" }]
console.log(objs);
const deleted = objs.removeObj({ id: 2, name: "Arrow" });
console.log({ objs, deleted })
```